# Referencing inline-Latex tables in Pandoc Markdown

Tags: tables, pandoc

I have resorted to defining a table using inline-Latex in a Pandoc Markdown document. The reason is that I need to group table rows (using a horizontal line only between certain rows).

I'm trying to get `pandoc-tablenos` to work with this inline-Latex table, by doing the following:

- Adding `Table: Caption. {#tbl:id}` below the table (with a single newline between this text and the last line of the inline Latex) (as described [here](https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-tablenos#usage))

  - *Result:* the verbatim text `Table: Caption. {#tbl:id}` is present in the output PDF (below the table) and `tbl:id` is not recognized as a valid ID

Example Pandoc markdown document with inline Latex table:

```
# Expressions

Test 123. Table:

\begin{footnotesize}
   \begin{tabular}{ | l l l | } \hline
      \textbf{Expression}        & \textbf{Meaning}            & \textbf{Associativity}     \\ \hline
      \texttt{e1 grouped by e2}  & Add a group to a grouping   & left    \\
      \texttt{e1 where e2}       & Filter a grouping           & left    \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{footnotesize}

Some more text. *I would like to reference the table here.*
```

I execute `pandoc` as follows to build a Latex document:

```
pandoc --standalone --from markdown -F pandoc-tablenos --pdf-engine=xelatex <input-file>.md -o <output-file>.tex
```

Comment: Please add some code, an example that demonstrate, what you have tried so far...

Comment: @DG' Good idea. I will do that.

Comment: Please add a small working pandoc document with an inline latex table. I suspect that you need to add the lable with `\lable{tbl:id}` but this is only a guess without the actual code

Comment: @DG' Done! I've also added the `pandoc` command that I use to convert the markdown to Latex.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the caption and table id within the latex table. Since you are using `tabular` and no floating environment, you have to use `\captionof` from the package `caption`. You can load that in the yaml-header:

```
---
header-includes: \usepackage{caption}
---

# Expressions

Test 123. Table:

\begin{footnotesize}
  \captionof{table}{A \LaTeX-table. \label{tbl:latex}}
  \begin{tabular}{ | l l l | } \hline
    \textbf{Expression}        & \textbf{Meaning}            & \textbf{Associativity} \\ \hline
    \texttt{e1 grouped by e2}  & Add a group to a grouping   & left                   \\
    \texttt{e1 where e2}       & Filter a grouping           & left                   \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{footnotesize}

Some more text. See table @tbl:latex
```

[image]

You can ignore the warning:

> pandoc-tablenos: Bad reference: @tbl:latex.

It just means, that you haven't defined the label in `pandoc-tablenos`-syntax

Comment: Trying to reference a table labeled this way using `@tbl:id` in the Markdown document results in an error from `pandoc-tablenos` (`Bad reference: @tbl:id.`) when I try to convert using `pandoc`.

Comment: @runeks - You can ignore the warning